# How to call web url from controller code asp.net mvc Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How do I call a url from controller. i.e. this one "http://xxx.ashx?Item=82f829e6&IsReadonly=false". It cannot be from a href link in the view but has to be from the controller. I am using asp.net MVC Core 1.1

Comment: Use HttpClient :)

Comment: I have tried that but is not a get or post or ... So I wonder what I should set contenttype to and how to trigger the send? Should I use SendAsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
public IActionResult YourAction()
{
    return Redirect("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Comment: Of course! Just me being emptybrained today. Thank you. Works like a dream.

Comment: Not sure how to do that but if you tell me, I'll do so.

Comment: Done so. I can only upvote to level 3. It won't led me go any higher. Thanks again.